# my jquery autocomplete function not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

so let say, i am using ajax to get a list of object from a asmx file, and after that i parse my list of object into json object, the output will be like this

```
[
    {
        "UserName": "hl",
        "FirstName": "hendra",
        "LastName": "lim"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "wd",
        "FirstName": "wildan",
        "LastName": "dan"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "gd",
        "FirstName": "genin",
        "LastName": "gn"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "tr",
        "FirstName": "tere",
        "LastName": "magda"
    }
]
```

but somehow my auto complete function did not work.

here is my code :

```
 var param;
       var resultarr;

       $(document).ready(function () 
       {
           param = document.getElementById('MainCT_dtvJobVac_PIC').value;
           $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           contentType: 'application/json;',
           data: '{keyword:' + JSON.stringify(param) + '}', // param in case utk lempar parameter.
           dataType: 'json',
           url: 'SvcUserList.asmx/GetUserList',
           success: function (result) 
           {
               resultarr = result.d;
               $('#<%#dtvJobVac.FindControl("PIC").ClientID%>').autocomplete
               ({
                   minLength: 0,
                   source: resultarr,
                   focus: function (event, ui) {
                       $("#MainCT_dtvJobVac_PIC").val(ui.item.FirstName);
                       return false;
                   },
                   select: function (event, ui) {
                       $("#MainCT_dtvJobVac_PIC").val(ui.item.FirstName);
                       //$("#<%#dtvJobVac.FindControl("PICKey").ClientID%>").val(ui.item.UserName);
                       //$("#results").text($("#<%#dtvJobVac.FindControl("PICKey").ClientID%>").val());
                       return false;
                   }
               });
           }
        })
      });
```

web service code :

```
[WebMethod]
        public string GetUserList(string keyword)
        {

            List<ADUserData> tes = new List<ADUserData>();

            ADUserData obj;



                obj = new ADUserData();
                obj.UserName = "hl";
                obj.FirstName = "hendra";
                obj.LastName = "lim";

                tes.Add(obj);

                obj = new ADUserData();
                obj.UserName = "wd";
                obj.FirstName = "wildan";
                obj.LastName = "dan";

                tes.Add(obj);

                obj = new ADUserData();
                obj.UserName = "gd";
                obj.FirstName = "genin";
                obj.LastName = "gn";

                tes.Add(obj);

                obj = new ADUserData();
                obj.UserName = "tr";
                obj.FirstName = "tere";
                obj.LastName = "magda";

                tes.Add(obj);

            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string output = jss.Serialize(tes);

            return output;
        }
```

any correction? what i do wrong here? thanks.

btw i put these jquery link src in my master site, is there something to do with version? or something else? thans in advance.

```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: "did not work" how? Errors? Unexpected output? Be more specific.

Comment: it show nothing, no error at all, can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you verified your function is even being called at all?

Comment: Debug i.e. put some breakpoints into the JS code and ensure that A) your code is being called, and B) your algorithm is working correctly e.g. variables contain valid data at important parts.

Comment: yes my function was called, i can tell it, because i put a breakpoint in my asmx file, i got a list of object and i serialize it as json object.

Comment: You should ensure that, assuming there are no other JavaScript errors (they will show up in the console) `resultarr` is correctly formatted for `.autocomplete`

Comment: `$('#<%#dtvJobVac.FindControl("PIC").ClientID%>')` this line can be your mistake.

Comment: `$('<%dtvJobVac.FindControl("PIC").ClientID%>')` should be like this. without sharp

Comment: still not working.. by the way i updated my post with some of my web service code, you might want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have following issue in your code,

1. Selector for the autocomplete is not correct
2. JSON format is not valid for autocomplete

Here is the solution for this,

```
$('#<%= dtvJobVac.FindControl("PIC").ClientID%>').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.UserName);
        return false;
    }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
        .append("<a>" + item.UserName + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Above code will update the autocomplete to support for `UserName` property. you can change the property name in the code.

Now you have only one thing to do. you have to force jQuery to support your JSON format.

```
$.extend($.ui.autocomplete, {
    filter: function (array, term) {
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
        return $.grep(array, function (value) {
            return matcher.test(value.UserName || value.FirstName || value.LastName || value.label || value.value || value);
        });
    }
});
```

All is done. now your code should works :) [Here is the working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LHp6S/1/)

Comment: thanks, this might working, i will try your code at monday as soon as i get to office, and will let you know if it is working, going to vote you up as well :)

Answer (score 0):

1 - I think you forgot to parse the `result` var to json.

```
success: function (result) 
{
    var resultarr = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
```

2 - The resultarr var does not have the structure expected for a jQuery autocomplete datasource :

> [ { "label": "Choice1", "value": "value1" }, ... ]

Comment: hello, i did like you said, there is something different, but still no luck :( so now autocomplete is working but with mallfuction, somehow it does not showing any text, but when i move the focus in the drop drown it shown text. such pain.